# Can't install Android drivers on PC

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, twrp

So I have this 4.4.2 Allview V1 Viper L aka Gionee Pioneer P6, with root (rooted using KingRoot) and I'm trying to install TWRP/CWM recovery (from what I read [here](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-5162.html) I can install whichever I want) on it to flash a custom ROM.

I have another identical device with CWM recovery and the custom ROM fully functional, but I got help from someone with the CWM recovery. I decided to try TWRP on the other device, but I have a problem.

I have **USB Debugging** activated from **Developer Tools** menu, but when I connect it to my PC, it doesn't install it properly. Opening **Device manager**, I can only see a difference when I connect it to my PC in **Disk Drives**, where there is *ALLVIEW V1_Viper_L USB DEVICE* and another copy of it, and in **Portable Devices** 2 things appear upon connection: *G:/* and *H:/* - that's it. No **Android ADB Interface** as it should have.

I have the latest version of Android SDK on my PC, with SDK tools installed. When I run the tool from the link above, **Easy Magic TWRP installer**, I get stuck at "Please plug in your device..." where I get right after: **ADB shell not working**.

I installed **Universal ADB driver**, I restarted the device, I restarted the PC, uninstalled and reinstalled the devices created in Device Manager after I connected the android to PC, I tried to update those drivers, I checked and un-checked USB debugging but nothing. I don't know what is wrong. I would gladly appreciate your help.

Comment: Try turning from MTP to PTP, should install extra divers then try `adb devices` from the terminal

Comment: You need VCOM and CDC drivers to get it detected (as it's a Mediatek device)